# How to delete a column in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Suppose I have 3 columns in a column family, I want to delete a column in a column family then  how to delete that particular column

Comment: Do you want to delete it from all rows or from just one?

Comment: I want to delete that column for all rows

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete particular column from column family, write this command into
 your hbase shell:

```
hbase> delete 't1', 'r1', 'fam1:c1'
```

- **t1** is table name.
- **r1** is row key.
- **fam1:c1** is your particular column (column_family:column).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can't we delete the column with out giving the row key ?